# The default fore- and background colors are reversed, how do I undo that?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have Photoshop CS5 extended. Since yesterday, pressing <kbd>D</kbd> the foreground color is white and the background black.

Pressing the switch icon or <kbd>X</kbd> the colors switch.

I need the default foreground color to be black and the background color white, as was the case before yesterday.

I tried to solve this by searching for relevant settings in the preferences, however without any success.

Comment: When working on a mask, the default *is* white foreground and black background. Do you have a mask highlighted int he Layer panel?

Comment: @Scott, yess, a mask is selected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working on a mask, the default *is* white foreground and black background.

Click a layer thumbnail rather than a mask to see the standard default colors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to click the default colour button, the little one in the corner here:

[image]